# Jenkins pipeline: How to build new artifacts only if has a new commit

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

```
stage('Checkout repo'){
    git branch: 'mybranch', 
    credentialsId: '6b83e39e-1c8c-44c2-9165-b1f5a857f6cb', 
    url: 'git@gitlab.com:myproject.git'}

stage('run tests'){
    sh 'mvn test'
}

stage('build artefact'){
    sh 'mvn clean package'
}
```

how to run tests and make new artifact only if has a new commit?
without a trigger

Comment: How are you causing the pipeline to run?

Comment: Just  i'm learning jenkins and instructor asks to find that way

Comment: The pipeline cannot magically run itself. It has to be either manually started or triggered by one of the build triggers in the job configuration page. It's not exactly clear what your requirements are. You should [edit] the question to expand on that and what is and what is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

You could use environment variables from the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) and create a condition:

```
if (env.GIT_COMMIT != env.GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT) {
  stage('run tests'){
    sh 'mvn test'
  }
  stage('build artefact'){
    sh 'mvn clean package'
  }
}
```

- GIT_COMMIT - SHA of the current commit
- GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT - SHA
  of the previous successfully built commit from the same branch.

Comment: Sadly this does not seem to work reliably. I get the error: ```Running in Durability level: PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 99: Expected a stage @ line 99, column 7.
         if (env.GIT_COMMIT != env.GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT) {
         ^

1 error```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to trigger your Jenkins job automatically.

1. You can use `SCM polling` in your pipeline job so that it will trigger your job each time there is a change.

   You can enable `Poll SCM` under ~Build Triggers` section of your pipeline job configuration.

   [image]
2. You can use `Webhooks` to trigger your jobs automatically when there is a change in your `GitHub`repository.

   Follow this [documentation](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-webhook-configuration) for `Webhook` implementation.
3. You can use `post-commit`hook to trigger the job when there is a commit in your repository.

   Create a file called `post-commit` under the `.git/hooks` directory of the repository and add the following script to it:

   `#!/bin/bash 
   curl --user 'user:pass' -X POST "http://server.org.com/jenkins/job/JOB-NAME/build" --data token=mytoken1 --data delay=0sec`