# Deploy at specified time of day only if build was triggered earlier in day

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins.

My node application currently deploys upon merge.

I would like my application to deploy at 2AM, but only if there was a merge earlier in the day.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), and a `Build Triggers > Poll SCM` enabled.

In the poll SCM field, you can write `0 2 * * *` (2AM).
That will trigger the job each time there is a change.

Other alternatives: "[Jenkins pipeline: How to build new artifacts only if has a new commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751151/6309)".

Comment: This looks right. Going to implement and verify before awarding. Thank you!